# Oracle ODBC dns connection

Tags: oracle, odbc, dns

My boss has asked me to set up a connection to our oracle Database (not local).

My first step was to download a oracle ODBC driver to use.

I downloaded and installed "ODBC Driver for Rdb, Release 3.3.2.0 64-bit (odbc3320_64.zip)".

I then decided to set up the DNS as I have done before using ODBC manager in windows 7.

Unfortunatly its not as easy as setting up a connection to a sql server.

Im wondering could some one walk me through the process or has anyone got a video link?

Many thanks

heres TNSPING result

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an Oracle database?  Or to a RDB database?  RDB is a database that is owned by Oracle (built originally by DEC) that runs primarily on VAX machines.

Comment: in all honesty im not entirly sure, the problem is there isnt elot of info since my boss only knows the IP and login details, ive already asked this my self.  Which link for a driver should i choose if its just an oracle dbo?

Comment: i have a funny feeling the best option is to download all the drivers and try 1 by 1 -.-

Comment: Ok ive VNC'd into the server, im looking at the ODBC dns, in System DNS it sgot "Driver" oracle in oraHome92. Not sure what this is, should i use this one on my pc?

Comment: That implies that there is an Oracle 9.2 client and an Oracle 9.2 ODBC driver on the server (is this the database server?  Or some other server)?  Getting an Oracle 9.2 ODBC driver for your PC would be a bit of a hurdle-- since 9.2 has been desupported for a while, it's not available for download any longer and it was never supported on Windows 7.  The 11.2 client should be able to connect to a 9.2 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to connect to an Oracle database, not an Oracle RDB database (RDB is a database that Oracle the company acquired from DEC), and assuming that the Oracle database is a reasonably recent version, and assuming that you do not have a version of the Oracle client installed on your machine now, the simplest approach is likely to download and install the 11.2 Oracle client on your machine and to choose to install the Oracle ODBC driver as part of that installation.

If you look at the [Oracle Database Software Downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), under Oracle Database 11g Release 2, there will be a set of links for both 32- and 64-bit Windows.  Choose the "See All" option for whatever version of Windows you have.   That should give you an option to download something called the "Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client" which is going to be a ~600 MB download.  Once you have that, run the installer and make sure to include the Oracle ODBC driver as part of the installation (you may need to do a custom install, I don't recall which of the client installation options includes an ODBC driver by default).

Comment: ill give this a go mate, really difficult with no information from your boss hehe

Comment: ok right driver i think, now im trying to get the dns to work.  Comes up "Unable to connect.  SQLState = 8004,  oracle ODBC ORA ORA - 12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier Specified

Comment: Ive TNSPinged and put the result on my post